# Transpose columns into diagonals

Tags: google-sheets

I feel like I'm asking something that is not possible with formulas in GSheets, but I've been amazed by the things this forum has been able to answer so I'm giving it a shot. :)

I get a report each morning that show an occupancy percentage for X days out. It can be exported as a csv file and the percentages are in a column. I have made a spreadsheet where we manually put this column in as a diagonal so it reflects the occupancy of corresponding day. I have linked to a sample of this. I have put the March 31 data from 'data' in as I would like to see it displayed on 'sheet1'.

Any way to get the data from 'data' to automatically transpose or display on sheet 1? It would also need to move down a date row (sheet1) for each date column (data) that is filled.

I hope I am explaining this clearly. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-PQ1GXRmsXrd7u9SHBT-gZkSYE6oLKkMttndmULEomY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the logic behind the way the data is organized in the Data sheet vs how you want it in Sheet1?

Comment: Will this need to be a rolling window? How often will you need to redefine the range dates/input new data?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this into C2 and drag across that top row.:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((COLUMN()-1=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""))
```

[image]

If you insist on a single cell array formula then this works:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( {IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((2=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((3=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((4=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((5=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((6=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((7=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((8=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((9=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((10=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((11=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((12=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((13=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((14=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((15=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((16=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((17=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((18=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((19=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((20=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((21=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((22=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((23=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((24=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((25=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((26=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((27=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((28=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),""),IFERROR(Data!$B$2:$B$29/IF((29=ROW(Data!$B$2:$B$29)),1,0),"")})
```

[image]

You must delete all cells that in the range to be filled by the array formula for it to work (C2:AD29).

Comment: Can't drag it because the formula in D2 needs D3 to be empty.  You need to use 1 formula for the entire table or only go across a row or down a column if using multiple formulas.

Comment: This formula creates a separate array for each column. I did not use the transpose function he originally suggested. They don't interfere with each other. @Karl_S

Comment: Dragging it to D2 gives this error: _Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D3_

Comment: Yes, you have to clear out all of the data he has input manually first.

Comment: See the updated Desired tab which is still only part of the desired output.  The OP is looking for the complete table to be filled in but only provided 1 day's worth.

Comment: It looks like you change the source range column, but I dropped the formula into your spreadsheet with the new column references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139801/discussion-between-jacob-edmond-and-karl-s).

Comment: Thank you for jumping on this so quickly!             I am not able to chat... sorry guys. Not enough rep points.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Karl_S, what you provided has worked great for me so far!